# Titanium Pass Textfield Value to New Window

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing, titanium, dom-events

I am attempting to take the value of a textfield and pass it to a new window (Javascript file) using Ti.App.fireEvent (http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App-method-fireEvent) so that I can eventually insert it into a database when a button is pressed... So far I have a variable that stores the value of the textfield called usernameValue. This will then be sent to an http parameter value. There has to be something simple that I'm missing.  Let me know if more information is needed to make this question more clear.

TexField where data originally comes from:

```
var username = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    //color : '#ffffff',
    top : 10,
    width : 300,
    height : 45,
    hintText : 'Username',
    keyboardType : Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
    returnKeyType : Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT,
    borderStyle : Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    clearButtonMode: Titanium.UI.INPUT_BUTTONMODE_ONFOCUS
});
```

Needs passed from login.js:

```
//FireEvent parameter passing!
var usernameValue = username.value;

Ti.App.addEventListener('sendDataToScreen', function()
{
    Ti.App.fireEvent('app:populateUsername', usernameValue);
});
```

IM.js retrieval:

```
//FireEvent Paremeter Passing!
Ti.App.fireEvent('app:populateUsername', usernameValue);
```

New Window (in case this helps):

```
//if logged in, open new window!
        var IM = Ti.UI.createWindow({
            url : 'IM.js',
            navBarHidden : false,
            // fullscreen:false

        });
        IM.open();
```

Button parameter passing where used:

```
//posting of IM onclick to database!!
postBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    if (chatBox.value != '') {

        createReq.open("POST", "http://***.php");
        var params = {

            post : chatBox.value,
            user : _data.username
        };
        createReq.send(params);

        //tap to repload and clear
        var rd = [];
        tableview.data = rd;
        setData();

    } else {
        var blankAlert = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
            title : 'Posting Error',
            message : 'Post cannot be empty',
            buttonNames : ['OK']
        });
        blankAlert.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when sending data

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('app:populateUsername', { "username" : usernameValue });
```

when receiving data

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('app:populateUsername', function(_data)
{
    // all the data passed
    Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(_data));

    // the value is here
    Ti.API.info("the name passed as a parameter " + _data.username));
});
```

Comment: The console output "the name passed as a parameter" does not show up and when put into usage, the debugger/simulator says "Can't find variable".  Any ideas?  See above button usage please.

Comment: I don't think the data actually passes to the new window at all given the debugger feedback.

Comment: the sample code I provided above works, please provide a simple test case where is does not work, no one really wants to rebuild your complete project to find the solution for you

Comment: The button parameter above is the test case.  If you mean something else, please let me know.

Comment: I reveresed the login and IM code.  The login.js contains the fire event and the IM.js contains the event listener.

Comment: I ran this: Ti.API.info("the name passed as a parameter " + _data);
 and the IM.js came back with an error "Can't find variable".